# MySql Query, Database design,query efficiency

Tags: mysql

I have been working on php and mysql for 1 year. I have come across some code in php, where the programmers writes a query which he encloses it in for loop or foreach loop, and the query gets generated as like this (takes 65.134 seconds):

```
SELECT * from tbl_name where PNumber IN('p1','p2'.......,'p998','p999','p1000')
```

In my mind I believe that query is horrible, but people who are working before me, they say there is no other way round and we have to deal with it. Then I thought it should be wrong database design. But cannot come up with the solution. So any suggestions or opinions are welcome.

Couple of things to add. Column is indexed and table has almost 3 million records. I have given you example as p1,p2 etc..But those are originally phone numbers like 3371234567,5028129456 etc. The worst part, that I feel is, this column is varchar instead of int or big int which makes the comparison even worse.My question is, can we call this a good query, or is it wrong to generalize and it depends on the requirement?

Comment: We cannot tell you if it is a badly designed database without seeing the database architecture.

Comment: and the question is: what should be selected? If you just want all entries, this WHERE statement is sick! But if you want specific 1000 entries where the selection is not defined via a time or any a criteria but only by the number, then i guess there is no way around that. Still this is a long time, do you have an index on PNumber?

Comment: If the list is fully sequential (all values 1-1000), you can remove the `p` and cast the resultant substring to an `INT`. That might be a lot faster than a giant `IN()`

Comment: If the column only stores all numbers with a `p` in front of them, it's most likely beneficial to replace this column with an integer. This would also allow you to a range query as @Michael suggests.

Comment: How about adding a second column that is BIGINT to store the phone numbers as a number? That way you don't lose the formatting of the phone numbers. Also, how do you decide which numbers to pick from the database? Does sorting them before putting them in the IN clause make any difference?

Comment: Maybe you can explain what the purpose of this query is. Why are you selecting want seems to be an arbitrary 1000 phone numbers? It seems to me that if you are doing a query prior to this to generate/find these numbers, you may want to look at doing an `INNER JOIN` on the previous query instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this with hopes that we can decrease the turnaround time by providing an example.

Check with your developers and see how they are producing the SQL command.

All those numbers must be coming from somewhere. Ask them where.

If the numbers are coming from a table, then we should simply `JOIN` those two tables.

EXAMPLE:

Granting that the phone numbers are stored in a table named `PHONE_NUMBERS` under a column named `Phone` -- and using your example `tbl_name` to which we match the column `PNumber`

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl_name AS t1
    INNER JOIN PHONE_NUMBERS AS t2
    ON t1.PNumber = t2.Phone
```

However, even as an example, this is not enough. Like @George said, you'll have to give us more information about the data structure and the data source of the phone numbers. In fact, depending on the kind of data you show us and the results you need, your SQL query might need to remain using an `IN` statement instead of an `INNER JOIN` statement..

Please give us more information...

Answer (score 0):

What can help us help you is if you could tell us the result of `explain` on your query.

ie:

```
explain SELECT * from tbl_name where PNumber IN('p1','p2'.......,'p998','p999','p1000');
```

This will give us some information on what the database is trying to do.